# Airflow on Docker start get ERROR:TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Tags: docker, hdfs, airflow

i want to extend the airflow on docker with providers hdfs:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#examples-of-image-extending

the Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.4
ARG DEV_APT_DEPS="\
     curl \
     gnupg2 \
     apt-transport-https \
     apt-utils \
     build-essential \
     ca-certificates \
     gnupg \
     dirmngr \
     freetds-bin \
     freetds-dev \
     gosu \
     krb5-user \
     ldap-utils \
     libffi-dev \
     libkrb5-dev \
     libldap2-dev \
     libpq-dev \
     libsasl2-2 \
     libsasl2-dev \
     libsasl2-modules \
     libssl-dev \
     locales  \
     lsb-release \
     nodejs \
     openssh-client \
     postgresql-client \
     python-selinux \
     sasl2-bin \
     software-properties-common \
     sqlite3 \
     sudo \
     unixodbc \
     unixodbc-dev \
     yarn "
     
USER root
RUN mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak \
  && echo 'deb https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/debian/ buster main contrib non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo 'deb https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo 'deb https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/debian/ buster-backports main contrib non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && echo 'deb https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ${DEV_APT_DEPS} \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

  
USER airflow
COPY --chown=airflow:root constraints-3.7.txt /opt/airflow/
COPY --chown=airflow:root ifxjdbc.jar /opt/airflow/jdbc-drivers/
RUN pip install --timeout=3600 --no-cache-dir --user \
  --constraint /opt/airflow/constraints-3.7.txt \
  --index-url https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple \
  --trusted-host pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn \
  apache-airflow-providers-apache-hive \
  apache-airflow-providers-apache-hdfs # this line will make a error in the future
```

it's build successful

but when i init it : `docker-compose up airflow-init`

there got an error

```
airflow-init_1       | ....................
airflow-init_1       | ERROR! Maximum number of retries (20) reached.
airflow-init_1       | 
airflow-init_1       | Last check result:
airflow-init_1       | $ airflow db check
airflow-init_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
airflow-init_1       |     from airflow.__main__ import main
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 28, in <module>
airflow-init_1       |     from airflow.cli import cli_parser
airflow-init_1       |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 621, in <module>
airflow-init_1       |     type=argparse.FileType('w', encoding='UTF-8'),
airflow-init_1       | TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
airflow-init_1       | 
airflow-224_airflow-init_1 exited with code 1
```

if the dockerfile remove 'apache-airflow-providers-apache-hdfs' then rebuild

it can init ok...

HELP~ i really need the provider of hdfs

Comment: Docker Compose it a developer tool. It is not a ready to go solution and debugging issues with it requires you to really understand what you are doing. PR https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/22304 is adding a chapter that explains this and warns users before they are departing to this adventure.

Comment: thanks for your answer ,But i really know what i do. i just want extending the airflow image .[https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#extending-the-image](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#extending-the-image) .

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more looking I think I know where your problem is - You are likely not using the "entrypoint" to run airflow. You should always use the original entrypoint https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html and you are lkely overriding it without your own entrypoint which does not initialize airflow environment properly.

Answer (score 0):

This gave me some trouble the issue is this: argparse is now in python core and must not be installed.
The package apache-airflow-providers-apache-hdfs requires snakebite-py3 and snakebite-py3 installs argparse.

**To solve the problem just add: RUN pip uninstall -y argparse to the end of your Dockerfile**